# Yum installing different version of ansible then stated.

Tags: ansible, redhat, yum

I want to install ansible 2.1 via yum (`yum install ansible`). yum info states the version is 2.1 when I install it I get a previous version.

I have tried cleaning yum, removing ansible completely and installing (`yum remove ansible` then  `yum install ansible`)

```
[root@server /]# ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ansible", line 124, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(C.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP, True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP'

[root@server /]# yum list installed ansible
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository epel-source is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: bay.uchicago.edu
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: centos.chicago.waneq.com
 * updates: mirrors.tripadvisor.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Installed Packages
ansible.noarch                                          2.1.0.0-1.el7                                          @epel
```

On a different server it does have `ansible --version` state it being 2.1

Comment: Could you have installed ansible with pip in addition to installing it with yum?

Comment: Start with `which ansible` and `rpm -ql ansible`.

Comment: And `rpm -qf $(which ansible)` to tell you which package (if any) owns the executable you're using.